# Pass array as function parameters for class constructor

Tags: php, oop

How can I pass an array as constructor parameters in class instantiation?

```
abstract class Person {

    protected function __construct(){

    }

    public static final function __callStatic($name, $arguments){
        return new $name($arguments);
    }

}

class Mike extends Person {

    protected function __construct($age, $hobby){
        echo get_called_class().' is '.$age.' years old and likes '.$hobby;
    }
}


// =============================================

Person::Mike(15, 'golf');
```

This should output

> Mike is 15 years old and likes golf

But I get second parameter missing in `Mike`'s constructor, because both parameters from `__callStatic` are sent as array into `$age`. My question is how can I send them as parameters instead of array?

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with PHP but shouldn't you be using 2x_ in the constructor instead of 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php) for this:

```
public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments){
    $reflector = new ReflectionClass($name);
    return $reflector->newInstanceArgs($arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `call_user_func_array()`, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php and a factory method:

```
class Mike extends Person {

    public static function instantiate($age, $hobby) {
        return new self($age, $hobby);
    }
    protected function __construct($age, $hobby){
        echo get_called_class().' is '.$age.' years old and likes '.$hobby;
    }
}
```

And then make a Mike like so:

```
abstract class Person {

    protected function __construct(){

    }

    public static final function __callStatic($name, $arguments){
        return call_user_func_array(array($name, 'instantiate'), $args);
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't do that. I need to be able to call `Person::Mike()`

Comment: This does exactly that.

Comment: but then I have to implement `instantiate` into all classes, this is not smart.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the static scope resolutor wrong

```
Person::Mike(15, 'golf');
```

That would mean you have a static method `Mike` inside the class `Person` and you're calling it statically.

Instead, you want to instantiate `Mike`

```
$mike = new Mike(15, 'golf');
```

If you want to call static things from `Person`, because `Mike` extends it, `Mike` can also call it statically.

```
Mike::staticMethod($args);
```

Comment: No I don't want to do that. I have a class Person that can return instances of people classes, I explicitly don't want to be able to call people classes constructors, that's why they are protected.

Comment: I added something to better deal with your static needs